# WPF Datagrid error : 'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, deferred

If I open the datagrid and click anywhere on it ,so after exit when I try to reopen it I get the above mentioned error.

I have read about using  myDataGrid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row); but I don't know how to use it.How to exactly stop the datagrid from edit/add new mode.

Comment: Please post your code in the question. The information you given cannot help the others to understand what's wrong at all.